# Iterate Over The Document & Subdocument in EJS

Tags: express, mongoose

I am creating a subdocument when I do my post for example on /gifts/new route. This new data is assigned to the user I select, and pass.

On my index route I have this:

```
Gift.find({}, function(err, allGifts) {
    if (err) {
        req.flash('error', err.message);
    } else {
        res.render('gifts/index', {
            title: 'Review Gifts',
            gifts: allGifts,
            breadcrumbsName: 'Gifts'
        });
    }
});
```

Back in the index.ejs template I'm doing a simple: `<% gifts.forEach(function (user) { %>` which is where my issue is. I need to find the user based on the `_id: 586aef6ffe5cd14ab6532889` thats in the gifts object over iteration. As you may know that there are many gifts which has different user _id:

How do I do that? As I was writing this I had a thought which is to inside the `} else {` do a `User.find{}, cb` just so I can look up the user by that _id which is what tried but couldn't get working.

*UPDATE*

Here is my gift schema per request:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Schema Setup
let giftSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Gift'
        },
        username: 'String'
    },
    giftNumber: Number,
    date: Date,
    status: {
        review: String,
        accepted: {
            type: String,
            redeemed: Boolean
        },
        declined: String,
        expired: String,
        pending: String,
        paid: String
    },
    giftDescription: String,
    giftAmount: Number,
    giftCode: String,
    redeemCode: String,
    passCode: String,
    senderFirstName: String,
    senderLastName: String,
    giftMessage: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Gift', giftSchema);
```

Here is the user:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    aliasFirstName: String,
    aliasLastName: String,
    username: String,
    phone: String,
    password: String,
    isAdmin: Boolean,
    addressLine1: String,
    addressLine2: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zipCode: Number,
    profilePic: {
        type: String,
        default: 'https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/0a07df079fd7a07e4cd0e5668835296c?s=80'
    },
    preferredPaymentMethod: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['', 'paypal', 'check', 'deposit'],
        default: ''
    },
    paymentPreference: {
        paypal: {
            email: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            }
        },
        check: {
            addressLine1: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            addressLine2: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            city: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            state: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            zipCode: {
                type: Number,
                default: ''
            }
        },
        deposit: {
            routingOrTransit: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            accountNumber: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            }
        }
    },
    lastLoginDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: could You provide the schema of Gift and User?

Comment: @num8er Ive updated the request with the gift and user

Comment: Yes, I'm writing the answer ;)

Comment: done, please check

Comment: You can always test to see what your `gifts` array looks like by doing something like: `<%= JSON.stringify("gifts", null, 4)%>` .Do you see an array of objects?

Comment: @jackblank little fix: `<%= JSON.stringify(gifts, null, 4)%>` (;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) fix Your `Gift` schema, see `user` attribute:

```
const 
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  Types = Schema.Types;

const schema = new Schema({
    user: {
      type: Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true,
      index: true
    },
    ...
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Gift', schema);
```

2) change Your db query code:

```
Gift
  .find({})
  .populate('user')  // populate will join user model to .user attribute of gift item
  .exec(function(err, gifts) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
    } 

    res.render('gifts/index', {
      title: 'Review Gifts',
      gifts: gifts,
      breadcrumbsName: 'Gifts'
    });
  });
```

if You want gifts of dedicated user so:

```
Gift
  .find({user: req.user._id})
  .populate('user')
  .exec(function(err, gifts) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
    } 

    res.render('gifts/index', {
      title: 'Review Gifts',
      gifts: gifts,
      breadcrumbsName: 'Gifts'
    });
  });
```

3) and get necessary data in `ejs` template like this:

```
<% gifts.forEach(function(gift) { %>
  User ID: <%= gift.user._id %><br/>
  Username: <%= gift.user.username %><br/>
  Fullname: <%= gift.user.firstName %> <%= gift.user.lastName %><br/>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Hello, I dropped the collection, to try again. It's hanging. Im testing this out now.

Comment: @JosephChambers yup, so I've just updated my answer's `2)` part with 2 options: `get all gifts` and `get all gifts of user` via taking `user` object from `request` object that's provided by `passport`

Comment: So, this seems to be working as far as posting to the user as I can see in the object

`{ __v: 0,
  username: 586afad4a4ff884d28b6ca97,
  giftNumber: 12345,
  date: 1984-01-23T00:00:00.000Z,
  giftDescription: 'Love',
  giftAmount: 100,
  giftCode: '123',
  redeemCode: 'Chambers',
  passCode: 'abc123',
  senderFirstName: 'Baby',
  senderLastName: 'Boy',
  _id: 586b0049e3e8174ea5305938 }`

However, in the index route when I do gift.user.firstName it says 
Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined.

Comment: @JosephChambers it's better to use solution as in my example where You've `user` attribute that has reference to `User` model and can be added to gifts by doing: `.populate('user')` to get related data that will help You to not to do many requests to get user's other fields. see updated answer where I use populated data: `Fullname: <%= gift.user.firstName %> <%= gift.user.lastName %>`

Comment: I got it to show, but still the same thing as undefined. I see:

'{ _id: 586b0049e3e8174ea5305938,
  username: 586afad4a4ff884d28b6ca97,
  giftNumber: 12345,
  date: 1984-01-23T00:00:00.000Z,
  giftDescription: 'Love',
  giftAmount: 100,
  giftCode: '123',
  redeemCode: 'Chambers',
  passCode: 'abc123',
  senderFirstName: 'Baby',
  senderLastName: 'Boy',
  __v: 0 }'

My username is the email address because because I wasn't able to change that.

Comment: happy that was helpfull (:

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get an object from an array. I'm assuming `gifts` is an array of objects. so I would use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Example using `find` with regular object:

```js
var inventory = [
     {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
     {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
     {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
 ];

var item = inventory.find(function(item){
 return item.name = "apples"
})
console.log(item)
```

you might want to do the same thing for `gifts` but using `<%%>` for EJS.

You also might need to to do `gifts.toObject().find()` If you are getting the documents straight from mongoose

Edit: I think you use `toObject()` on the document not an array. I've had several times docs not appearing, but when I use toObject and it appears.

Comment: `I've had several times docs not appearing, but when I use toObject and it appears` - seems like it was issue of asynchronous call (: